# Typescript def for object value that returns extended generic

Tags: typescript

I have a feeling this isn't possible, but I figure I ask.
I defined the following:

```js
type Params<TState> = {
    init?: (arg: TState) => TState;
}

function getInit<TState> (params: Params<TState>) {
    return params.init
}

const state = {
    h: 1,
}
const init = getInit<typeof state>({
    init: (initState) => ({
        ...initState,
        d: 'd'
    })
});
type INIT = typeof init;
```

The problem is `INIT` returns

```js
type INIT = ((arg: {
    h: number;
}) => {
    h: number;
}) | undefined
```

when it should return

```js
type INIT = ((arg: {
    h: number;
}) => {
    h: number;
    d: string; // THIS IS MISSING
}) | undefined
```

and I don't know how to define `Params` to show the extended return value.

here's the playground link if you want to play around with this
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACghgJzgWwM4B4AqBlYdgQB8UAvFAN4BQUNUAlgHZ3AD8AXFABSIDmHOeAgEpSxAfggBuSgF9KlAGYBXBgGNgdAPYMoPCMACSTYFlwTinMIhSoO8JGlOCiIqrSgJ9ShDqsPUAHSMzLLyqtqowFCREqQU1LQAFhwAjAA0oeEMkfTGcXqGxuigkJoK0c6EnG60wcAcnHVmwqJcNe40AV1NzhkdtAAmHADkA8MJNDJCskLSlCXQBgByBphxC2W5zJJAA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the args to `init` and the return value are different types, then they should be different types.

It sounds like you want to take any input type, and then allows the function to return a value of a type that extends the input type. So that's *two* generic parameters, not just one.

That makes the `Params` type look like this:

```
type Params<
    TStateInput,
    TStateOutput extends TStateInput
> = {
    init?: (arg: TStateInput) => TStateOutput;
}
```

Now the `TStateInput` type can be your args, and `TStateOutput` can be the return value with whatever extra properties are added.

`getInit` now would like this:

```
function getInit<
    TStateInput,
    TStateOutput extends TStateInput
> (params: Params<TStateInput, TStateOutput>) {
    return params.init
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=27&ssc=19&pln=15&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBACghgJzgWwM4B4BQUdQCoDKwcwEAkgHZgCuwANNrocaQPK03BQQAepFAE1T4iJclVqYAfFAC8UAN6McASworgAfgBcUABSIA5ruZjKnAJRyZpth1oBuTAF9MmAGbUKAY2AqA9hRQhhDAlBpYuCIs4pwMUbYQ7MCc3HwQgsKJ5pIyemCIKKi68Eho6NkS9NFiyZxSVkpRCKHUCEEFZagAdGoaLm7egahcI2JyispQABa6AIwMrkMUI1B9XPIhYerAek2467p666KkuqCQ-u5QY6RWsnn7UTjdrycx8c84AroA5AK-KbOCwuCxOTDLVYtVDUAA2GzWO003T2M3mACYAMxQYGYaFwrTdaZQAD0JKgAHd-AgANaoPEQGHw5ECUnkqm01BAA)

Comment: I had a feeling I had to pass another generic. Not really what I wanted but I guess that what static analysis is about

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to @alex-wayne answer: this will not give you exactly what you want (you can't have that) but may fit your requirements:

Define `TState` as

```js
type TState ={
    h:number,
    [key:string]: string | number
}
```